# How do I get rid of useless scroll space on css

Tags: html, css

Okay so this is my first html/css/javascript website. I am not sure what's going wrong basicly I used css to make the background image fit, then I tried to add an image link using

```
    <div id="project_button" style="position:relative; top: 1000px; left: 1000px" >
```

the result being 1000 pixels of scroll room on the horizontal scroll bar.
There are similar results when I try to edit the location with

```
    margin-left:1000px
    margin-top: 1000px
```

Except it will be the vertical scroll bar that has extra room.

```
    <html>
          <head>
          <title>Home Page</title>
          <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
          <meta http-equiv="Imagetoolbar" content="no">
          <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
          <!--

          if (document.images) {

          var button1_up = new Image();
          button1_up.src = "project1.gif";

          var button1_over= new Image();
          button1_over.src = "project2.gif";
          }

          function over_button(){
           if (document.images) {
       document["buttonOne"].src = button1_over.src
      }
    }

          function up_button() {
               if (document.images) {
               document["buttonOne"].src = button1_up.src
          }
    }
    //-->
    </SCRIPT>
    <style type="text/css">
    html {height:100%;}

    body {height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}

    #bg {position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;}


    </style>
    <!--[if IE 6]>
    <style type="text/css">
    html {overflow-y:hidden;}
    body {overflow-y:auto;}
    #bg {position:absolute;
    padding-right:800px;
    margin-right:-800px;}

    #project_button {position:static;}
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
          <div id="page1" style='position: relative'>   
      <div id="bg"><img src="WebBacking.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" alt="">
          </div>
      <div id="project_button" style="position:relative; top: 1000; left: 1000" >
        <a href="projects.html" onMouseOver="over_button()"
                 onMouseOut="up_button()">
        <img src="project1.gif" alt="click me" 
        width="1800" height="200" name="buttonOne" 
        border=0>
        </a>
      </div>
          </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

This is the rest of my code. Any help is appreciated.

btw when I scroll vertically or horizontally the background still fits but because the image's location is static it moves when scrolling. I should also mention that when i set

```
  top: 0; left:0;
```

the scroll bar is removed. this also goes for top-margin.

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Comment: Your CSS should be in the <head> tags, mixing it with the HTML is very bad practice and very outdated.

Comment: remember this is my first. i have yet to learn convention

Comment: Do you really need to be supporting IE6 in your code?? Do you really expect to get any visitors using IE6? Hint: virtually no-one is still using it, and those few who are still using it are used to seeing sites that don't look right. My strong advice is to drop support for IE6. Maybe even for IE7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want a scroll bar at all in certain elements add `overflow:hidden` to the css. this way everything outside the element will be clipped, and no scroll bars are visible.

Answer (score 1):

Also try `overflow:auto`. It shows scroll bar when the content overflows only.